# Failed to start server error when trying run docker using the tensorflow/serving image

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow-serving

I am using the tensorflow/serving image and run into this error trying run the docker file.

**Step 1: > pulled the tensorflow serving image**

```
docker pull tensorflow/pull
```

**Step2: Stored my models into a (saved-models) folder within my project folder(detection-potato-lite)**

```
Elijah-A-W@DESKTOP-34M2E8U MINGW64 /d/myn/ML_Prediction_Project/New_folder/detection-potato-lite
$ ls
   Api/  'Data Eda'/   models.config   Plant/   saved-models/
```

**Step 3: Created the models.config file in the Project folder to render the models dynamically using tensorflow serving**

```
    model_config_list {
    config {
        name: 'potatoes_model'
        base_path: '/detection-potato-lite/saved-models'
        model_platform: 'tensorflow'
        model_version_policy: {all: {}}
}
```

**Step4: Get an error(No such file/directory) when trying run the image in Windows Powershell**

```
PS C:\Users\Elijah-A-W> docker run -t --rm -p 8501:8501 -v D:/myn/ML_Prediction_Project/New_Folder/detection-potato-lite:/detection-potato-disease tensorflow/serving --rest_api_port=8501 --model_config_file=/detection-potato-lite/models.config

Failed to start server. Error: Not found: /detection-potato-lite/models.config; No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two problems here:

1. The directory path you bind to the volume is different to the one you list locally (New_Folder vs New_folder)
2. You bind local directory ‘detection-potato-lite’ to docker directory ‘detection-potato-disease’. When you specify the location of the config file and base-path for your application to run in docker, it must be relative to where you store it in docker so it will be ‘detection-potato-disease’.

EDIT:

By using `-v D:/myn/ML_Prediction_Project/New_Folder/detection-potato-lite:/detection-potato-disease` in your docker run command, you are binding your local directory (D:/myn/ML_Prediction_Project/New_Folder/detection-potato-lite) to a directory within the Docker container (/detection-potato-disease).

This means that when your application runs inside the Docker container, all your files/folders that were on that local directory now exist in '/detection-potato-disease'.

So you have two options:

1. Modify the 'base_path' in your models.config file from `/detection-potato-lite/saved-models` to `/detection-potato-disease/saved-models` AND modify '--model_config_file' in your docker run command from `--model_config_file=/detection-potato-lite/models.config` to `--model_config_file=/detection-potato-disease/models.config`
2. Change your docker run command to be `docker run -t --rm -p 8501:8501 -v D:/myn/ML_Prediction_Project/New_folder/detection-potato-lite:/detection-potato-lite tensorflow/serving --rest_api_port=8501 --model_config_file=/detection-potato-lite/models.config`

EDIT 2:

You'll need to add another closing `}` bracket on line 7 of the models.config file after the previous fix I have mentioned.

Comment: thanks Jason, its my first time using docker and tfs, so still trying learn how stuff works, i get the 1st problem but still not understand the 2nd.   So is it the **models.config_file** or its  **base_path** or the **--model_config_file=/detection-potato-lite/models.config** in the powershell. Which location am i changing to detection-potato-diseaase!!

Comment: You'll have to change the 'base_path' field in your models.config file to '**/detection-potato-disease/saved-models**'. You'll also have to change the '--model_config_file' flag value in your docker run command to '**/detection-potato-disease/models.config**'.

Comment: An easier option might be just to change your docker command to `docker run -t --rm -p 8501:8501 -v D:/myn/ML_Prediction_Project/New_folder/detection-potato-lite:/detection-potato-lite tensorflow/serving --rest_api_port=8501 --model_config_file=/detection-potato-lite/models.config
`

Comment: @andylacron I have edited my answer to try and explain

Comment: Thanks @ jasonS when i have tried both methods, when i run `docker run -t --rm -p 8501:8501 -v D:/myn/ML_Prediction_Project/New_folder/detection-potato-lite:/detection-potato-disease tensorflow/serving --rest_api_port=8501 --model_config_file=/detection-potato-disease/models.config` gives an error `[libprotobuf ERROR external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/text_format.cc:324] Error parsing text-format tensorflow.serving.ModelServerConfig: 7:6: Expected identifier, got:
Failed to start server. Error: Invalid argument: Invalid protobuf file: '/detection-potato-disease/models.config'`

Comment: Even after changing the models.config file, here is the github repo (https://github.com/Elijah-A-W/Project-using-Tfserving-with-Docker/blob/main/models.config)

Comment: Ah just noticed that the models.config file is also missing a closing `}` bracket on line 7

Comment: Thanks, definately that was the issue, its now running. One more question, how do i get the **url / endpoint** something like this **endpoint = "http://localhost:8501/v1/models/model:predict"**  inorder to get access to the tfs models!!

Comment: Since it is a post request I don't think you'll be able to access it via a URL. You should be able to query it through Postman by sending a Post request (I am not sure on the parameters/request body since I am unfamiliar with TensorFlow)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247000/discussion-between-jasons-and-andy-lacron).